# Cookie usage in a Java application

Tags: java, cookies

I would like to use cookie in my java application. Looking at the Java API it seems there is no support of cookie in java.net package. The only support I found is about servlet, i.e., java.servlet.http.Cookie.

The only (minimal) support I found is in class java.net.CookieHandler, but it seems to be quite complex compared to java.servlet.http.Cookie management.

Thanks,
Giuseppe

Comment: You want to use a cookie in a non HTTP scenario ? If not then why doesn't the `java.servlet.http.Cookie` work for you ?

Comment: Yes, my application need to open http request and get http responces. But I am not server side, I do not have servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [URLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) you can get/add cookies by using the headers and adding request property "Cookie" respectively. This is native to Java SE. A 3rd party library that's also good is [Apache's HttpClient/](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). The class you mention  java.servlet.http.Cookie is only available to web-apps deployed in a Java EE Application server.

Comment: Right, but I have to take care about cookie details, i.e., path and expiration. While probably the servlet cookie support manage all this complexity automatically.

Comment: I think all that is taken care of by the server (i.e. each cookie has it's domain, if it's expired it will no longer be sent to the client etc). Look at HttpClient's options for cookie handling, I think you'll get all you need from there. This all holds true if what you want to implement in Java is an HTTP Client that connects to various already existing HTTP Servers. If you want to start your own HTTP Server in Java SE, you have such an option using Java SE 6 or above (look up the HttpServer javadocs)

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a jre only software, so I think I'll use the request properties as connection level.